# How to get Bootstrap to work with Angular?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am a beginner in Angular. I am setting up a sample project but Bootstrap is not working.

I installed bootsrap using npm and a bootstrap folder exists in node_modules but the browser inspector says the bootstrap file status is 404/Not Found.

Here is my code:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Node server won't serve up files from your node_modules directory unless you explicitly put a path to it like:

```
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/'));
```

You're better off moving the bootstrap.css to a different directory that your Node server will serve files from or to link to bootstrap from a CDN (such as https://cdnjs.com/libraries/twitter-bootstrap/)